# org.mule.tooling.client.startup.toolingnotavailableexception tooling instance could not be started

Tags: anypoint-studio

org.mule.tooling.client.startup.toolingnotavailableexception tooling instance could not be started

does anyone know how to fix this, I am using java version 17 on windows 10

Comment: And which version of Studio?

Comment: Anypoint Studios Version 7.14

Answer (score 0):

The currently last released version of Anypoint Studio is [7.14 which requires OpenJDK 11](https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/studio/anypoint-studio-7.14-with-4.4-runtime-release-notes#compatibility) to execute. Using a different version of Java/OpenJDK is not supported. No previous release supports any JDK greater than JDK 11 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Windows -> Preferences -> Anypoint Studio -> Tooling and restart studio services.